# Where does Anki store media?

Tags: anki, search-folder, appdata

Where does Anki store media such as pictures, sound recordings, etc? I have tried to export the deck, but it doesn't show the location:

[image: image description]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Windows 7 Win10, default Anki 2.0 installation stores the media files inside this folder:

> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Anki2\yourankiaccountname\collection.media

If this isn't the correct folder for you, find it by following this step by step:

1. Open your Anki
2. Chose your Anki account for which you want to locate the media files
3. Go to **Tools** Menu
4. **Preferences...**
5. **Backups** tab
6. click on **Open backup folder**
7. You will find the **collection.media** folder as a sibling folder of the **backups** folder

Shorter version: Open Anki → Chose your Anki account → **Tools** Menu → **Preferences...** → **Backups** tab → **Open backup folder** → find **backups** folder → go up one level → and you find your **collection.media** folder

Answer (score 14):

On Ubuntu the right path is:

`~/.local/share/Anki2/Benutzer 1/collection.media`

Comment: `Benutzer 1` should be changed to your user name. The default is `User 1` on mac.

Comment: `cd ~/.local/share/Anki2/User\ 1/collection.media`

Answer (score 8):

[Anki Manual - File Locations](https://docs.ankiweb.net/files.html#file-locations)

`collection.media` will be in folders `<your_user_name>` in the directory:

> Windows: `%APPDATA%\Anki2`
>
> Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/Anki2`
>
> Linux: `~/.local/share/Anki2` or `$XDG_DATA_HOME/Anki2`

For example, it's `~/Library/Application Support/Anki2/User 1/collection.media` on a mac by default.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to search for a specific image or recording, then the result will show the directory.

In Windows:
[image: image description]